# How use several item renderers in one in List?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flex4

I decided to make a simple tool for social networking. 
There is a list (in the picture), which has a complex itemRenderer which included two more itemRenderers (IR).

[image: app]

The first (social networks) get data from the global dataProvider, the second (resources) is formed depending on what social network in the first IR selected. The dataProvider of the second IR created on the basis of another dataProvider directly in IR code.

```
protected function soc_itemClickHandler(event:ItemClickEvent):void
            {
                if (event.label == 'selected') {
                    dp = new ArrayCollection();//dataprovider of the second IR
                    for (var k:int = 0; k < Copypaste.socials.length; k++) 
                    {
                        for (var j:int = 0; j < Copypaste.resources.length; j++) 
                        {
                            var socObj:Object = Copypaste.socials.getItemAt(k);
                            var resObj:Object = Copypaste.resources.getItemAt(j);
                            if (socObj.selected == true ||socObj.selected == 'true') {
                                if (resObj.social == socObj.uid) {
                                    dp.addItem(resObj);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

All fine, but the problems begin when I want to select another social network - one IR affect the other, the data do not match. And the List can be sorted by dragging of the items, then all the data in the second IR disappear, and the checkboxes in the first IR become disselect.

How to build the architecture of this app?

Comment: You should store state in ItemRenderer's data field. So that when item (data field) is changed, IR could update it's state correctly.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work, because I have one IR in othe IR. Triple nesting.

Comment: It doesn't matter how much nesting you have. You should apply that strategy to every IR.

Comment: If I create a data provider in an IR, it will not work. This results a loss of data while item dragging, or to change the states of all other IR when the state of one IR will change.The only way to create Vector.<ArrayCollection> in the main class, which will get data to all IR second level. But this is monstrous.

Comment: Did you try what @DenisKokorin said, but turn of virtualization?